# How to generate XML file using angular 2?

Tags: xml, angular

I was trying to generate XML files using Angular 2. I used xml-Writers, but it always gave me an error when I tried to generate tags with namespace. 
The error is

> XML Parsing Error: Prefix not bond to a namespace' at the IR name space:

This is an image of the error: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPsC1.png)

My code is

```
xw.startDocument()
     .startElementNS('IR','GenHead','http://www.iredes.org/xml/DrillRig')
         .writeElement('FileCreateDate', `${date}${tz}${time}`).endElement()
         .startElement('root').writeAttribute('foo', 'value').writeElement('tag', 'Some content').endElement()
         .startElement('entry')
           .startElement('entry').endElement()
         .endElement()
         .startElement('entry2').writeAttribute("urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b93C-0003939e0af6").endElement()
         .startElement('entry').endElement()
     .endElement()
   .endDocument();
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the library [xml-js](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js) can help you. 
It can transform json to xml.

Here an example from the page:

```js
var convert = require('xml-js');
var json = require('fs').readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
var options = {compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4};
var result = convert.json2xml(json, options);
console.log(result);
```